# JavaScript radiobutton previous and new value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have two tables with radio buttons. I need to change the previous radio button value to `false` and the new value to `true` and send both via Ajax to the controller. So far I have managed to send back the new `true` value to the DB.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table').on("change", 'td .radiobtn' , function(){
         $.ajax({
             url: '/home/radiobuttonvalue',
             type: 'POST',
             data: {id:$(this).data("id"), value:$(this).prop('checked')},
             success: function(data){
                 console.log(data);
             }
        });
    });

    data.forEach(function(account) {
        var object = account.type === 'purchase' ? $('.purchase tbody') : $('.sales tbody');
        var checked = !account.type_default ? "" : "checked";

        object.append(`<tr><td><input class="radiobtn" type="radio" "value="${account.type_default}" name="radio-${account.type}" checked="${checked}" data-id="${account.id}"></td>`);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? Plus try explaining this sentence more **What i need to do is change the previous radiobutton value to false and the new value to true** more.

Comment: So there is lets say two radiobuttons on the html i have for all intends and purposes lets call them rb1 and rb2. rb1 is selected as default with the value of true, and when i press rb2 i need to change the rb2 value from false to true and then send that value back to database. And i have succeeded on that. But what i have to do also is change rb1 value to false as it is not selected and send that value back to database also.

Comment: Can you please show the html? Thanks.

Comment: The whole purpose of this is to give the user a default account. Currently if i press all the buttons, all of the accounts will change to a default or on the database as true.

Comment: It ll be more clear if you show me your html for table and radio buttons.

Comment: It is appended on the code: object.append(`<tr><td>etc...`)

Comment: rb1 and rb2 are one set of radio buttons or two sets or radio buttons?

Comment: There are two sets of buttons, but rb1 and rb2 is on the same button group. They are on the purchase table. There are also rb3 and rb4 on sales group.

Comment: So you want when you click rb1, rb2 becomes false and vice versa?

Comment: Why do you need to change the value of rb2 from true to false? Isn't it false in the first place?

Comment: Exactly. So when the radiobutton is pressed the "old" radiobutton becomes false, the "new" radiobutton becomes true. I tought it could be something like saving the previous to a variable and on change the variable previous to have value of false. Or do it with selector.

Comment: So it is allready false? In that case i still need to get the value somehow.

Comment: In short, you want the previous and new value of the radion button to be sent through ajax?

Comment: Yes. The new value is allready send and handled to db. The previous needs to be send as false.

Comment: You dont need to change the radio button value. Just send false in your ajax request.

Comment: You want something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/x1hn5q3x/

Comment: Well, got the problem solved in the backend. Simply find purchases with value true and set it to false, then put the new purchase value to true.